# how can i use input as a txt file in hexstring in this program to convert hex to dec

Tags: python, python-2.x

how i edit this code that in hexString i can use input as a txt file which can contains hexstrings

```
def main(): 

    hexString = "4f3343"

    print "Hex String: %s" %hexString
    print "Int array -> %s" %hexStringToIntArray( hexString )


    return

def hexStringToIntArray( hex ):

    hex = hex.replace( "-", "" )

    result = []

    for i in range( 0, len(hex), 2 ):

        hexVal = hex[i : i+2] # sub string between i and i+2
        intVal = int(hexVal, 16)
        intStr = str(intVal)

        result.append( intVal )

    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

to open a .txt file, you can use this command :

```
file_name = "File.txt"          # Path to the .txt file
file = open(file_name, "r")     # Open the .txt file in reading mode
line = file.readlines()         # Create a list [] with each element being a line
file.close()                    # Close the file
```

Let's suppose this is your .txt file :

```
4f3343
4f1243
4a2341
```

The code above give you this list :

```
[4f3343\n, 4f1243\n, 4a2341]         # If no Enter after the last line
# OR
[4f3343\n, 4f1243\n, 4a2341\n]       # If Enter after the last line
```

To delete the "\n", you can loop on the list :

```
for elt in line:
    elt = elt[:len(elt)-2]
```

So that's it for the example of what you can do with .txt file, now figure out how you wanna use this ;) Good luck !

If I were you, I would place hexString as a parameter of main.

EDIT : for the loop part to delete the "\n", if you wanna take into account both cases (enter or no after last line), you can use an if "\n" in elt condition.